# How can I extract values from a array JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON:

```
[[{"product_name":"prod-1","product_url":"http:\\www.google.com"}]]
```

**CODE JS:**

```
 var giftLabel = window.checkout.giftLabel; // return json

 var array = JSON.parse("[" + giftLabel + "]"); // transform in a array

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            var parse = JSON.parse(array[i][j]);   //this line not working
            console.log(parse.product_name);       //this line not working
        }
    }
```

I want to extract the values from this JSON and choose an example

**OUTPUT:**

```
prod-1
http:\\www.google.com
```

Can you please tell me where I am wrong and why can't I extract the values from JSON correctly?

Comment: first thing `giftLabel` is not json string its a array .so no need to parse

Comment: Like @prasanth said, `[[{"product_name":"prod-1","product_url":"http:\\www.google.com"}]]` is an **array**, not a `json`

Comment: Why are you adding `[]` around a JSON string which already has 2 `[]` wrapped around it? Just `JSON.parse(giftLabel)`. Remove the `JSON.parse` from inside the loop

Comment: See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-satoshi-ogr7s)

Answer (score 0):

It seem your `[[{"product_name":"prod-1","product_url":"http:\\www.google.com"}]]` is already in JS object. So you can always access it via

```
var x = [[{"product_name":"prod-1","product_url":"http:\\www.google.com"}]];

console.log(x[0][0].product_name);
```

Or if you value is in JSON text, then parse it first:

```
var x = JSON.parse("you json text");
```

then continue as above example.

Here's the working in loop:

```
var x = JSON.parse("json  text");

x.forEach(function(i){
    i.forEach(function(ii)){
          console.log(ii.product_name);
    }

});
```

Comment: OK thank you very much
  but I don't need an iterative structure, if for example I have a JSON line, then there is no array [0] [0], right?

Comment: Ok understood. Will update the answer

Comment: ok, I look forward to ... I'm curious how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var parse = array[i][j];
output = Object.values(parse)
```

output = ['prod-1', 'http:\www.google.com']

Object.values will return an array of all the values inside the passed object

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = [
  [{
    "product_name": "prod-1",
    "product_url": "http:\\www.google.com"
  }]
]

for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < d[i].length; j++) {
    if(typeof d[i][j] != "undefined"){
    console.log(d[i][j]["product_name"]);
    console.log(d[i][j]["product_url"]);
}
  }
}
```